# Upsert Return ID

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to get the inserted or updated id from a stored procedure, i tried 2 different ways

I'm not allowed to use `If exists(select ....)` for performance reason

**1- using OUTPUT**

```
    @firstName varchar(30),
    @Telephone int

        AS
        BEGIN transaction
            UPDATE [PHONE_BOOK].[dbo].[USER]
                       SET TELEPHONE= @Telephone
                       output inserted.USERID
                     where FIRST_NAME = @firstName

    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    begin
            INSERT INTO [PHONE_BOOK].[dbo].[USER]
           ([FIRST_NAME]
           ,[TELEPHONE])
           output inserted.USERID -- or output SCOPE_IDENTITY()
     VALUES
           (@firstName
           ,@Telephone)
  end
```

C# code

```
IList<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", "Mike"));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Telephone", 9514256));

            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "[dbo].[INSET_USER]";
                    command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                    foreach (SqlParameter oPar in parameters)
                        command.Parameters.Add(oPar);

                    object x = command.ExecuteScalar();

                }
            }
```

1. In case of update ==> `x` is Correct
2. In case of delete ==> `x` is null

**2- using OUTPUT parameter**

```
@firstName varchar(30),
@Telephone int,
@userId int output

AS
BEGIN transaction
    UPDATE [PHONE_BOOK].[dbo].[USER]
               SET TELEPHONE= @Telephone
             where FIRST_NAME = @firstName
            -- i can't find different way to set @userId than doing a select which is not acceptable
    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    begin
            INSERT INTO [PHONE_BOOK].[dbo].[USER]
           ([FIRST_NAME]
           ,[TELEPHONE])
     VALUES
           (@firstName
           ,@Telephone)
           set @userId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        end
```

c# Code:

```
IList<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@firstName", "Mike"));
            parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Telephone", 9514256));

            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "[dbo].[INSET_USER]";
                    command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                    foreach (SqlParameter oPar in parameters)
                        command.Parameters.Add(oPar);
                    command.Parameters.Add("@userId",0).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    var x = command.Parameters["@userId"].Value;

                }
            }
```

1. In case of update ==> `x` is -1
2. In case of delete ==> `x` is correct

how can i fix this? i perefere first option as i don't need to pass output parameter to the stored procedure

Comment: How about making the ID an OUTPUT parameter in the stored proc?

Comment: Then in my c# code i have to pass a value for the ID? if yes then what value i have to pass? also if i pass the id as parameter then in case of update then i have to Call a select in order to assign the id to the updated value which i want to avoid

Comment: Are you looking for the number of rows effected on an update?

Comment: normally the number of rows is always one because 'fullname' is a unique, i only wnat to return the id of the inserted or updated row

Comment: "idea is to insert or update huge number of records"

Then I think maybe you need to look at bulk insert type operations than this RBAR stuff. I gave my answer to your code below, but it sounds like you have an architecture issue too. Consider using SSIS or something if you need to insert/update more than 1000 rows at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you aren't getting your output value in this case is because you are *select*ing it rather than *return*ing it. You can pick it up from the first result set if you don't want to change your proc - but ExecuteScalar suppresses result sets, so you'll want to use ExecuteReader or something like that. However, there is a standard pattern for this and you aren't following it, so I'll post it just to be nice - I'm sure it's been covered elsewhere though.

Standard SP pattern -

```
create proc UpsertMyTable (
    @parameter int
) AS

declare @result int

if exists (select 1 from MyTable where value = @parameter) begin
    UPDATE HERE
end else begin
    INSERT HERE
end

set @result = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

return @result
```

And then in your C# code, basically what you have in your example is correct except the way you've done the parameters is redundant and a performance problem...

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnString)) {
    sqlConnection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "[dbo].[PROC_UPSERT_SHARE]";
        command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

        command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fullName", "dwfae"));
        command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", "aze"));
        command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@root", "aze"));
        command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@creationDate", new DateTime(2000, 10, 10)));
        command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastAccessDate", new DateTime(1999, 11, 11)));
        command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lastWriteDate", new DateTime(1990,12,12)));
        command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@subShareCount", 20));
        command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@serverId", "serverx"));

        object x = command.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Something like that will be much faster. Please consider this type of thing even if you think the impact might be small.

Comment: as mentioned in my post, i don't want to perform select 'if select' is not acceptable for performance reasons 

i'm going to simplify my question,

Comment: It is acceptable. IF EXISTS is the right way to do this. Think about it... is a failed update any faster or slower than an IF EXISTS? You're thinking, well sometimes the update will work and that's faster, and if your app does a lot of updating and little inserting, you might see a marginal improvement, but IF EXISTS is pretty fast, and most apps insert way more than they update. And yes, sending back a return parameter is less network data than sending a result set with one column and one row.

Comment: Ok, try the following and you will understand what i mean
create a table with 10 mil of records. then try to insert/update one  records using IF(select ) and check performance
the select statement will reduce performance

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong, in your solution i have to perform 2 selects first one to check if record exists second one in case of update to set the return parameter?

Comment: You haven't posted your SQL Server version but have you considered MERGE (which does an UPSERT in one statement). @Jasmine has made a goo observation - if you are loading a lot of data this is not the way to do it. You should BULK INSERT into a staging table then MERGE from that. Two Bulk operations will perform much quicker than the RBAR solution you are trying here

Comment: Merge sounds very interesting, what i understood from the documentation online is that i have to pass a table to a stored procedure. is it possible to pass mulitple tables (DataSet) if yes then will am able to insert/join inside the merge? googling :-)

Comment: Look at BCP and BULK INSERT - basically the same process. They read from a file. BCP performs bulk inserts from the command line, it's an executable program. BULK INSERT is a SQL statement which starts that same process from a SQL script. If neither of those will work, SSIS is your next best bet. We barely ever write custom importers these days - ETL is a solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using RETURN or OUTPUT parameter along with ExecuteNonQuery(), it automatically populates values into the variables. ExecuteScalar() is not required.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/05/07/a-simple-example-on-how-to-get-return-and-out-parameter-values-using-ado-net.aspx